# InfoPath User Profile Issue after migration with Sharegate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, infopath, user-profile-service, infopath-data-connections

I m migrating SP 2013 to SP Online using Sharegate tool. After migration GetUserProfileByName property is not working in Infopath form because it is accessing one On-Premise web service. How to fix this issue in SharePoint Online now? Please suggest the steps.

Comment: Have you contacted Sharegate? Their support is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Migration issue, it's appears to be SP2013 On-Prem has a different UserProfile Service to the SPOnline. Therefore you need to remap the userprofile data within the form itself. Setup new Data Connectors to the new service.
I haven't mastered this yet, but I have the same issue with a form that calls the Users Manager. 
Does anyone have some Old to New User Profile Mappings?